# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ">" when expecting one of the following

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have the following sql code when i run it it gives an error PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ">" when expecting one of the following:. ( * @ % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem

```
SELECT     n.id,
               n.ain,
               to_char(n.open_time +4/24,'dd-mon-yy hh24:mi') open_time,
               n.by,
               to_char(n.close_time+4/24,'dd-mon-yy hh24:mi') close_time,
               n.closed_by,
               n.contact_name,
               n.category,
               n.assignee_name,
               n.affected_item,
               n.medium,
               n.name,
               n.Status,
               n.escllated,
               to_char(n.actual_start+4/24,'dd-mon-yy hh24:mi') actual_start,
               to_char(n.actual_finish+4/24,'dd-mon-yy hh24:mi') actual_finish,
               n.actual_duration,
               n.title,
               dbms_lob.substr(n.description,3000) description
    FROM       MYTABLE n
    where      n.OPEN_TIME >= to_date('01-may-20') AND n.OPEN_TIME < to_date('18-may-20') AND n.INCIDENT_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT a1.INCIDENT_ID  FROM   INCIDENTSA1 a1 ) ;
```

I get the following error

```
**Execute Query: ORA-06550: line 21, column 175:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ">" when expecting one of the following:
   . ( * @ % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   like4 likec as between || multiset member submultiset
The symbol "( was inserted before ">" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 21, column 221:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:
   . ( * % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   like4 likec as between || multiset member submultiset**
```

Can any one help on this

Comment: You have not shown 175 lines of code (which I don't recommend).  So, the error message doesn't make sense in the context of the code you have provided.

Comment: @stranger90 - Wild guess: Remove the semicolon. Is the code part of bigger batch or PL/SQL block?

Comment: As a side observation, not relevant to your immediate problem.  _Do not use 2-digit years!!!!!!_  Perhaps you are too young to appreciate it, but the Y2K bug was real, and you are just recreating it.